# Quickest way to recode ranges of day of year to month and count?

Tags: r, date, count

I have a data set containing two sets of ranges of days (a day being coded as the day number of the year). For each row, I would like to count the number of days per month that these ranges correspond to in total.

In my example data, the columns 'deb' and 'fin' are the start and end days of the first sub-range within each row, and 'deb2' and 'fin2' are the limits of the second sub-range.

```
d <- data.frame(deb = c(1, 32, 90, 91), fin = c(31, 59, 91, 91),
                deb2 = c(50, 0, 0, 0), fin2 = c(60, 0, 0, 0))

d
#  deb fin deb2 fin2
#1   1  31   50   60
#2  32  59    0    0
#3  90  91    0    0
#4  91  91    0    0
```

For example, for row 1, the first range (from 'deb' to 'fin') goes from day 1 to 31, and the second goes from day 50 to 60.

After counting the number of days per month for the two ranges together, I expect to get something like:

```
#     jan feb  mar
#[1,]  31  10    1
#[2,]   0  28    0
#[3,]   0   0    2
#[4,]   0   0    1
```

(NAs instead of zeroes are not an issue)

I tried several solutions like the following three ones (the third one 'g3' is the fastest) and also tried using the tidyverse which reveals to be a magnitude slower. I wonder whether there is a quickest alternative, because in the real life I have tons of rows. The issue seems to be in the conversion from a range to a list of month references, but perhaps also in the way of counting.

```
f1<-function(deb,fin,deb2,fin2,...) {
  f<-factor(c(deb:fin,deb2:fin2))
  levels(f)<-list(jan=1:31,feb=32:59,mar=60:91)
  table(f)
}
g1 <- function() do.call(rbind,d %>% pmap(f1))

K <- vector(10,mode="character")
K[1:31] <- "jan"; K[32:59] <- "feb"; K[60:91] <- "mar"
f2 <- Vectorize(function(deb,fin,deb2,fin2) table(c(K[deb:fin],K[deb2:fin2])))
g2 <- function() do.call(bind_rows,f2(d$deb,d$fin,d$deb2,d$fin2))

L <- K
names(L) <- 1:91
f3 <- Vectorize(function(deb,fin,deb2,fin2) c(L[deb:fin],L[deb2:fin2]))
g3 <- function() {
  as.matrix(do.call(bind_rows,f3(d$deb,d$fin,d$deb2,d$fin2))) -> m
  z <- unlist(map(list("jan","feb","mar"),
                   function(y) apply(m,1,function(x) sum(x==y,na.rm=TRUE))))
  dim(z)<-c(nrow(d),3)
  z
```

}

UPDATED
Some benchmarks follow. I added to my trials the solution from Chinsson12 that behaves well with an elegant solution.

```
firstOfMths <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-01"), by="month")
daysPerMth <- c(1L, cumsum(as.integer(diff(firstOfMths))))
chinsoon12 <- function() 
  t(apply(d, 1, function(x)
      table(cut(c(x["deb"]:x["fin"],x["deb2"]:x["fin2"]), daysPerMth, labels=month.abb, include.lowest=TRUE, right=TRUE))
```

))

```
N <- 500
d<-data.frame(deb=rep(c(1,32,90,91),N),fin=rep(c(31,59,91,91),N),deb2=rep(c(50,0,0,0),N),fin2=rep(c(60,0,0,0),N))
microbenchmark(g1(),g2(),g3(),chinsoon12())
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr              min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# g1()         571.3890 615.1020 649.7619 639.6632 662.4808 976.9566   100
# g2()         306.7141 341.3056 360.9687 353.1227 373.8194 505.0882   100
# g3()         282.2767 304.4331 320.4908 314.2377 325.8846 543.4680   100
# chinsoon12() 429.7627 469.6998 500.6289 488.5176 512.0520 729.0995   100
```

Comment: how do you want to handle Feb 29?

Comment: No feb 29 in my example. Either the factor or the K vector could be changed if the actual year requires it. It is just a question of a global parameter without incidence on questions of speed. @chinsoon12

Comment: Because you wish something "faster", please also provide a data set of relevant size for benchmarking (in addition to your nice little toy data). Do you always have two sets of "deb" and "fin" columns? Cheers

Comment: @Henrik You could replicate the 4 rows N times. In the real life N would be 10 million (but data is not replicated :-(). And yes, I need two ranges of dates in something like 25 % of the cases. But separating the two cases can be a source of optimisation, thanks!

Comment: Would g3 works if there are number in later months? Does g1 to g3 give the same output?

Comment: @chinsoon12 The example was designed for a year of 3 months (and 32 days in March)! As g1 and g2, g3 should be adapted,in the list of monts and in their numbers form the `dim`. Anyway I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `findInterval`, `Map` and `table`:

```
# create breaks to be used in findInterval
b <- <- as.numeric(format(seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "month"), "%j"))

# use Map to expand the day of year ranges by row
# use findInterval to convert day of year to month number
# use the month numbers to index month.abb 
l <- Map(function(from, to, from2, to2) month.abb[findInterval(c(from:to, from2:to2), b)], d$deb, d$fin, d$deb2, d$fin2)

# create a row index
i <- rep(1:nrow(d), lengths(l))

# use table to get a contigency table of row indices and months
table(i, factor(unlist(l), levels = month.abb))
# i   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#   1  31  10   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#   2   0  28   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#   3   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
#   4   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Seemed faster than `g3()` on a larger data set (`d <- d[rep(1:nrow(d), 1e4), ]`).

Comment: It doesn t seem faster. It is really very faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The OP has requested to find the *quickest way to recode ranges of day of year to month and count* and has [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439368/quickest-way-to-recode-ranges-of-day-of-year-to-month-and-count#comment91826069_52439368) that the production dataset includes 10 M rows. The OP has conducted a benchmark test with a problem size of 2000 rows and test data which cover only 3 months instead of 12 months.

Although the question has an accepted answer I wondered

1. how a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach using `melt()`, `foverlaps()`, and `dcast()` would compare to the other answers
2. and how a more realistic benchmark with varying problem sizes would look like.

#### foverlaps()

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
cols <- c("deb", "fin")
# reshape sub ranges from wide to long format
long <- melt(setDT(d)[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn", measure.vars = patterns(cols),
     value.name = cols)[deb > 0]
# create data.table with monthly breaks and set keys
b <- seq(as.IDate("2018-01-01"), as.IDate("2019-01-01"), "month")
mDT <- data.table(abb = forcats::fct_inorder(month.abb), 
                  deb = yday(head(b, 12L)), 
                  fin = yday(tail(b, 12L) - 1L),
                  key = c("deb", "fin"))
# find overlaps between sub ranges and monthly breaks
foverlaps(long, mDT)[
  # compute days in overlaps
  , days := pmin(fin, i.fin) - pmax(deb, i.deb) + 1L] %>%
  # reshape to wide format for final result
  dcast(rn ~ abb, sum, value.var = "days", fill = 0L, drop = FALSE)
```

> ```
>    rn Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
> 1:  1  31  10   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> 2:  2   0  28   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> 3:  3   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> 4:  4   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
> ```

#### Benchmark

The benchmark code below compares

- the `foverlaps()` approach,
- OP's own approaches `g1`, `g2`, and `g3` (modified to handle 12 months),
- [Henrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52449326/3817004), and
- [chinsoon12's now deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441914/3817004).

[AntoniosK's `tidyverse` answer (now deleted)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52441220/3817004) has not been considered because the OP had [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52439368/quickest-way-to-recode-ranges-of-day-of-year-to-month-and-count#comment91825478_52441220) that this approach is 30 times slower than his own `g2` approach.

For the benchmark, the problem size is varied (`n_rows` = 100, 1000, 10000) as well as the share of rows with two ranges (p_sr_2 = 10%, 50%, 100%). The maximum problem size has been choosen with respect to the long run times of some of the approaches.

The different approaches differ also in the class of the result (i.e., `data.table`, `matrix`, `tibble`, and `table`) and the number of columns. Therefore, emphasis was put on writing an appropriate check function.

```
library(bench)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

bm2 <- press(
  p_sr_2 = c(0.1, 0.5, 1), # share or rows with 2nd sub range ]0, 1]
  n_rows = 10^seq(2, 4, 1),
  { # create test data
    set.seed(1L)
    d0 <- t(replicate(n_rows, sample(365L, 4L) %>% sort())) %>% data.table()
    setnames(d0, c("deb", "fin", "deb2", "fin2"))
    idx <- sample(nrow(d0), (1 - p_sr_2) * nrow(d0))
    d0[idx, c("deb2", "fin2") := 0L]
    str(d0)
    
    mark(
      foverlaps = {
        d <- copy(d0)
        cols <- c("deb", "fin")
        long <- melt(setDT(d)[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn", measure.vars = patterns(cols),
                     value.name = cols)[deb > 0]
        b <- seq(as.IDate("2018-01-01"), as.IDate("2019-01-01"), "month")
        mDT <- data.table(abb = forcats::fct_inorder(month.abb), 
                          deb = yday(head(b, 12L)), 
                          fin = yday(tail(b, 12L) - 1L),
                          key = c("deb", "fin"))
        foverlaps(long, mDT)[, days := pmin(fin, i.fin) - pmax(deb, i.deb) + 1L] %>% 
          dcast(rn ~ abb, sum, value.var = "days", fill = 0L, drop = FALSE)
        # returns a data.table with 13 columns and 0 for missing values
      },
      g1 = {
        f1 <- function(deb, fin, deb2, fin2, ...) {
          f <- factor(c(deb:fin, deb2:fin2))
          levels(f) <- list(jan = 1:31,
                            feb = 32:59,
                            mar = 60:90,
                            apr = 91:120,
                            may = 121:151,
                            jun = 152:181,
                            jul = 182:212,
                            aug = 213:243,
                            sep = 244:273,
                            oct = 274:304,
                            nov = 305:334,
                            dec = 335:365)
          table(f)
        }
        do.call(rbind, d %>% purrr::pmap(f1))
        # returns a matrix with 12 named columns and 0 for missing values
      },
      g2 = {
        K <- vector(10, mode = "character")
        K[1:31]    <- "jan"
        K[32:59]   <- "feb"
        K[60:90]   <- "mar"
        K[91:120]  <- "apr"
        K[121:151] <- "may"
        K[152:181] <- "jun"
        K[182:212] <- "jul"
        K[213:243] <- "aug"
        K[244:273] <- "sep"
        K[274:304] <- "oct"
        K[305:334] <- "nov"
        K[335:365] <- "dec"
        f2 <-
          Vectorize(function(deb, fin, deb2, fin2)
            table(c(K[deb:fin], K[deb2:fin2])))
        template <- matrix(
          integer(0), ncol = 12L, 
          dimnames = list(NULL, c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", 
                                  "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"))) %>% 
          tibble::as.tibble()
        do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, c(list(template), f2(d$deb, d$fin, d$deb2, d$fin2))) 
        # returns a tibble with 12 columns and NA for missing values 
      },
      g3 = {
        K <- vector(10, mode = "character")
        K[1:31]    <- "jan"
        K[32:59]   <- "feb"
        K[60:90]   <- "mar"
        K[91:120]  <- "apr"
        K[121:151] <- "may"
        K[152:181] <- "jun"
        K[182:212] <- "jul"
        K[213:243] <- "aug"
        K[244:273] <- "sep"
        K[274:304] <- "oct"
        K[305:334] <- "nov"
        K[335:365] <- "dec"
        names(K) <- 1:365
        f3 <-
          Vectorize(function(deb, fin, deb2, fin2)
            c(K[deb:fin], K[deb2:fin2]))
        m <- as.matrix(do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, f3(d$deb, d$fin, d$deb2, d$fin2)))
        z <- unlist(purrr::map(list("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", 
                                    "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"),
                               function(y)
                                 apply(m, 1, function(x)
                                   sum(x == y, na.rm = TRUE))))
        dim(z) <- c(nrow(d), 12)
        z
        # returns a matrix with 12 columns and 0 for missing values
      },
      henrik = {
        d <- copy(d0)
        b <- as.numeric(format(seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-12-31"), 
                                   by = "month"), "%j"))
        l <- Map(
          function(from, to, from2, to2) month.abb[findInterval(c(from:to, from2:to2), b)], 
          d$deb, d$fin, d$deb2, d$fin2)
        i <- rep(1:nrow(d), lengths(l))
        table(i, factor(unlist(l), levels = month.abb))
        # returns an object of class table with 12 columns and 0 for missing values
      },
      chinsoon12 = {
        d <- copy(d0)
        firstOfMths <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2019-01-01"), by="month")
        daysPerMth <- c(1L, cumsum(as.integer(diff(firstOfMths))))
        g <- ceiling(seq(1, ncol(d)) / 2)
        t(apply(d, 1, function(x) {
          x <- unlist(by(x, g, function(k) seq(k[1L], k[2L])), use.names=FALSE)
          table(cut(x, daysPerMth, labels=month.abb, include.lowest=TRUE, right=TRUE))
        }))
        # returns a matrix with 12 named columns and 0 for missing values
      },
      check = function(x, y) {
        cat("Run check: ")
        xdt <- as.data.table(x) %>% .[, .SD, .SDcols = tail(seq_len(ncol(.)), 12L)] 
        if (tibble::is_tibble(y)) {
          y <- dplyr::mutate_all(y, function(x) dplyr::if_else(is.na(x), 0L, x))
        }
        if (is.table(y)) y <- matrix(y, ncol = 12L)
        ydt <- as.data.table(y) %>% .[, .SD, .SDcols = tail(seq_len(ncol(.)), 12L)]
        result <- all.equal(xdt, ydt, check.attributes = FALSE)
        if (!isTRUE(result)) {
          print(result)
        } else cat("OK\n")
        return(result)
      }
    )
  }
)
```

The timings of the benchmarks can be plotted :

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Please, note the logarithmic time scale.

Apparently, the share of rows with two ranges doesn't have a visible effect on performance in contrast to the number of rows. For smaller problem sizes, `henrik`'s approach is the fastest approach confirming OP's observations. However, for problem sizes of 1000 rows and more the `foverlaps` approach is significantly faster. For 10 k rows, `foverlaps` is about one to two magnitudes faster than the other approaches.

Also, the memory requirements differ strongly:

```
bm %>%
  tidyr::unnest() %>%
  ggplot(aes(expression, mem_alloc, color = gc)) +
  ggbeeswarm::geom_quasirandom() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_grid(p_sr_2 ~ n_rows, labeller = label_both)
```

[image]

Again, please note the log scale.

The `foverlaps` approach allocates about one to two magnitudes less memory than the other approaches.

#### Benchmark part 2

Due to the long run times (and my impatience), above benchmark was only conducted for up to 10 k rows. Also [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52449326/3817004) tested only 40 k rows. So, I wondered if the `foverlaps` approach would be capable to process 10 M rows (the size of OP's production dataset) in reasonable time.

Unfortunately, my code to create the input data turned out to be too slow for problem sizes of 1 M rows or greater. So, I had to optimize (and benchmark) this part separately.

Only the `foverlaps` approach is benchmarked with the share of a second range fixed to 25% as stated by the OP.

```
library(bench)
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
bm5 <- press(
  n_rows = 10^seq(2, 7, 1),
  { # create test data
    cat("Start to create test data", format(Sys.time()), "\n")
    p_sr_2 <- 0.25 # share or rows with 2nd sub range ]0, 1]
    set.seed(1L)
    long <- data.table(rn = rep(seq_len(n_rows), each = 4L),
                      day = sample(365L, 4L * n_rows, replace = TRUE))
    setorder(long, rn, day)
    dups <- long[, which(anyDuplicated(day) > 0), by = rn]$rn
    if (length(dups) > 0) long[
      rn %in% dups, 
      day := replicate(length(dups), sample(365L, 4L) %>% sort(), simplify = FALSE) %>% unlist()]
    d0 <- dcast(long, rn ~ rowid(rn), value.var = "day")[, rn := NULL]
    setnames(d0, c("deb", "fin", "deb2", "fin2"))
    idx <- sample(nrow(d0), (1 - p_sr_2) * nrow(d0))
    d0[idx, c("deb2", "fin2") := 0L]
    str(d0)
    rm(long)  # free the memory
    tables()
    cat("Test data created", format(Sys.time()), "\n")
    
    mark(
      foverlaps = {
        d <- copy(d0)
        cols <- c("deb", "fin")
        long <- melt(setDT(d)[, rn := .I], id.vars = "rn", measure.vars = patterns(cols),
                     value.name = cols)[deb > 0]
        b <- seq(as.IDate("2018-01-01"), as.IDate("2019-01-01"), "month")
        mDT <- data.table(abb = forcats::fct_inorder(month.abb), 
                          deb = yday(head(b, 12L)), 
                          fin = yday(tail(b, 12L) - 1L),
                          key = c("deb", "fin"))
        foverlaps(long, mDT)[, days := pmin(fin, i.fin) - pmax(deb, i.deb) + 1L] %>% 
          dcast(rn ~ abb, sum, value.var = "days", fill = 0L, drop = FALSE)
        # returns a data.table with 13 columns and 0 for missing values
      },
      min_time = 2
    )
  }
)
```

The run time of the 10 M rows case was about 23.7 seconds on my system. The run time is increasing nearly linear for problem sizes above 1000 rows. The slight upward bend for 10 M rows might be due to memory limitations on my system.

```
bm4 %>% 
  tidyr::unnest() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(n_rows, time, colour = expression)) +
  geom_smooth(data = . %>% dplyr::filter(n_rows > 10^3), 
              method = "lm", se = FALSE, colour = "blue", size = 1) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  scale_x_log10() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "line", size = 1) +
  ggtitle("time vs n_rows")
```

[image]

Please, note the double logarithmic scale.